# Pass the entire row as an additional argument to UDF in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In order to pass the entire row as an additional argument to Spark UDF in Scala I use `struct("*")`, for example:

```
df.select(myUDF($"name",struct("*")))
```

How to do the same in PySpark?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the way to do it is

```
df.select(myUDF(f.struct(*list(df.columns))))
```